# PL/SQL - Use of variables in nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql, cursor

I'd like to do something like this with PL/SQL:

```
for ACCOUNT in account_cursor
loop

   for related_data in (select something from table where some_column = ACCOUNT.column)
   loop

   endloop;       

endloop;
```

(caps for emphasis)

I'm away from my dev environment so I  can't test this  out, so please ignore any minor syntactical errors. I am more concerned about whether I can  use the variables in this way.

EDIT:

An explination of what I'm trying to achieve. I have two huge tables: accounts and log. I want to get the log data for a specific few accounts. Because of the number of records a straight select/join is extremely slow. I am trying to speed up the proccess by first selecting the accounts I am interested in and then joining these to the log table. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be mixing an Explicit cursor (`account_cursor`) with an implicit cursor (`related_data`)...

Aside from ENDLOOP needing to be `END LOOP`, it's syntactically correct & valid.  You can [see examples of both types of cursors in this link](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/oracle-9i/oracle-cursors.html).  But I wonder what you're actually doing to see if the cursor approach is actually necessary.

Comment: Essentially I have two very large tables. I want to select a small number of accounts and get all of their entries in the data table. I've written the query using joins/where clauses and I'm looking for possible speed improvements using this approach.

Comment: +1 for "But I wonder what you're actually doing to see if the cursor approach is actually necessary.". Most of the cases, this turns out to be unnecessary and a big hit on performance.

Comment: @Peter: Databases are SET based, not procedural/OO.  It's very likely a single query is the best performing option, but without details it's difficult to provide examples.

Comment: @Rajesh: Agreed.  Most common issue to SQL performance is the fundamental understanding that SQL is SET based, not procedural/OO programming.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the response above before using this approach. Technically, yes, you can access the variables .. something like this.

```
for v_dept_rec in (select deptno from dept where deptno in (10,20)) loop
     for v_emp_rec in (select empno from emp where deptno = V_DEPT_REC.DEPT_NO) loop

      <<<Process here>>

     end loop;
end loop;
```

> "I've written the query using
>   joins/where clauses and I'm looking
>   for possible speed improvements using
>   this approach"

Invariably, this is pretty slow as this is row-by-row processing. If you can post a representative code for your logic, you will get responses which indicate how do process the same in Sets.

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh observed, doing this in a cursor will be very slow.

A straight select/join of relatively few values should only be slow on huge tables if the query isn't using appropriate indexes - check that indexes on the account number exist in both accounts and log tables. If they do, check that your query is using them in the explain plan.